# Measure precisely a resistance value

Tags: resistance, measurement, precision

Basically, I'm tasked to study the electrical properties of different screws (all in an unspecified titanium alloy, some fully anodized, others only the head) based on previous measurements that estimated the resistance around 0.15 Ohm for the one shown below.

I wanted to try a few different methods the see what was the resistance in DC, before moving on AC where i will study the impedance in function of frequency.
In DC, the way I was considering doing the measurements is linked below.

I've tried different configurations. I'm not using crocodile clip, because the wires have a higher impedance, and they don't stay put. So, I'm using twisted wires and "pinch grips".

The results are more stable (around 235 mOhms) than my first try with a 2 point measurement, there is no more significant wild fluctuation. However, I get very similar resistance value for configuration 1 and 2. Why is that? Also, when I try to include the head of the screw in the measurement, the values get really weird. Is it because it is anodized, or am I just doing something wrong?

I know the way I'm doing things is not optimal, so what could I improve, or which method should I use in order to obtain precise measurements?

Thank you for helping me !

the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dwxV.jpg

Comment: If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: your still wrapping multi-strand wire around a metal screw. That's not a reasonably good connection, so this was fair and squarely closed as duplicate to your previous question, since you haven't addressed the main problem we've pointed out.

Comment: You want something like a meter wheatstone bridge, where one side is made of wire.   Wire length is equivalent to resistance.